# Laravel 5.4 auth::check() false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I want to make my index page with both guest and auth functions.

When guests visit, they could try logging in; And after login, it will show the user's info such as username.

Route `routes/web.php:`

```
Route::get('vendor', function () {
    return view('vendor.home');
})->name('vendor')->middleware('web');
```

in blade template i use `Auth::check()` to authentication but failed.if i use `middleware(['web','auth:vendor'])` if guest will redirect to login page

```
@if(Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{route('vendor.login')}}"> <strong><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Login </strong> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{route('vendor.register')}}" class="btn btn-primary oval btn-lg"> <strong>Register</strong> </a></li>
                @else
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('vendor.logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Log Out</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @endif
                    {{ dd(Auth::check()) }}
```

Every time I logged in successfully, it will still show login button instead of user name button, after I REFRESH the index page.

this result
[image]
[image]

Comment: Depending on your version you can use `@guest ... @endguest` or `@auth ... @endauth` in Blade.

Comment: `@guest` and `@auth` not working

Comment: You have to add middleware auth on your route

Comment: if i add middleware auth on `->middleware(['web','auth']);` guest will deny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This my answer

```
@if(Auth::guard('vendor')->check())
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::guard('vendor')->user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('vendor.dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('vendor.logout') }}" >Log Out</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li><a href="{{route('vendor.login')}}"> <strong><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login </strong> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{route('vendor.register')}}" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"> <strong>Register</strong> </a></li>
                @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

try replace `Auth::` with `\Auth::` or `auth()`

```
@if(\Auth::guest())
                <li><a href="{{route('vendor.login')}}"> <strong><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Login </strong> </a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route('vendor.register')}}" class="btn btn-primary oval btn-lg"> <strong>Register</strong> </a></li>
            @else
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ \Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ route('vendor.logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            @endif
                {{ dd(\Auth::user()) }}
```

Comment: try ,result is null

Comment: Use `auth()->user()` also returns null? You need to check again from the controller.

Comment: Try `\Auth::check()` please. `\Auth::user()` returns the actual user logged in. `\Auth::check()` checks if user is logged in and valid.

Comment: if i use `$this->middleware('auth:vendor');` in construct Auth::user() working, but guest will redirect to login. i do not went